# Opposite text on title page

Tags: titles, article, signatures

I want to get text on opposite side. I have got signature definition so I can use it instead of this dots. This is my current progress:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1} 
    \centering
    {\scshape\Huge\bfseries Uniwersytet Zielonogórski \par}
    {\scshape\Huge\bfseries w Zielonej Górze \par}

    \vspace{2cm}
    \raggedright
    \LARGE Kierunek: \textsc{\textbf{Fizyka Techniczna}} \par
    \LARGE Specjalność: \textsc{\textbf{Fizyka Medyczna}} \par

    \vspace{2cm}
    \centering
    {\LARGE\textbf{Dawid HANIEWICZ} \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\LARGE\bfseries Wyznaczanie mas dla stanów podstawowych ciężkich jąder 
    atomowych w ramach modelu makroskopowo-mikroskopowego z wykorzystaniem 
    parametryzacji modif{}ied Funny-Hills \par}
    {\LARGE (Macroscopic-microscopic description of ground-state masses of 
    heavy nuclei with modified Funny-Hills parametrization) \par}

    \vspace{2cm}
    Praca inżynierska napisana \par
    pod przewodnictwem: dra~Piotra \textsc{Jachimowicza} \par
    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \vspace{1.5cm}
    Akceptacja promotora: \par
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \signature{0}{1.8}
    \vfill
% Bottom of the page
    {\large Zielona Góra, \the\year r. \par}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have so far?

Comment: @samcarter done

Comment: Can you make the code fragement compilable? For example how is `\signature` defined?

Comment: Have you tried to do that with a tabular with p{} column style, optionnaly in a centered context like the center environment ?